# Whenever I try to boot a Linux Distro from a USB it goes to an eternal black screen

Tags: boot, usb

I've tried countless of USB booters, such as Universal Usb, Rufus, Unetbootin. They seem to work fine as I can boot to the point to where boots to the options menu, where it says you want to install or try before you install or what have you. However whenever I try to install or test out the OS before installing it, it takes me to black screen which can't get out off without powering off.

Comment: Which distro is this? Have you tried more than 1?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the wrong video driver. Try editing the kernel boot line and add `single` or `1` to the end and see if it can boot to a non-GUI command-line.

Comment: Or `nomodeset`, `noapic`, etc... there are lots of troubleshooting / compatibility options to try. Ubuntu's iso menus usually have the common ones under "F6" I think